# Forbidden Patterns Policy missing with VS2015?

Tags: tfs, version-control, visual-studio-2015, commit, pre-commit

I'm trying to add a check-in policy to prevent certain file types from being committed to our source control, however when I go to add a check in policy from within VS2015 the listed options available in the "Add Check-in Policy" window isn't displaying "Forbidden Patterns Policy" as an option:

[image]

I got to this option by doing the following:

- Navigating to Team Explorer
- Clicking on "Settings"
- Under "Team Project" hitting "Source Control"
- Clicking the "Check-in policy" tab
- Pressing "Add" to bring up the "Add Check-in Policy" window (as seen above)

How can I set-up the forbidden patterns policy in VS2015? Has it moved?

I can confirm that this policy is currently not set-up on our source control. We are using TFS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah finally found out how to get it! To get the option to add the "Forbidden Patterns Policy" to Visual Studio 2015 you need to install "Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools". You must install the version which matches you VS; ei I was running VS2015 so I needed Power Tools 2015.

You can download it here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1

Comment: Also note that in order for the forbidden patterns policy to apply, all other members of the team must also install VS power tools, otherwise they'll always receive an error message when trying to check something in

Comment: Thanks for posting this! Solved my issue!